# Did Ilya Ponomarev confess that he is behind the antisemitic mobs in Dagestan?

Tags: russia, russo-ukrainian-war

On October 29, 2023, [an antisemitic mob stormed Uytash Airport near Makhachkala, Dagestan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2023_wave_of_antisemitism_in_the_North_Caucasus#Makhachkala_Airport) in Russia.

[PolitNavigator](https://www.politnavigator.net/evrejjskijj-pogrom-obedinil-patriotov-i-liberalov-v-nenavisti-k-zelenskomu-i-lyubvi-k-kadyrovu.html) claims (in Russian):

> Fugitive extremist and former State Duma deputy Ilya Ponomarev has already openly admitted that he coordinated the Jewish pogrom at Makhachkala airport through his controlled telegram channels.

Russian writer and journalist, [Dmitry Bykov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dmitry_Bykov) makes similar claims in this (Russian) [interview](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8f-cSiJHj-Q).

I was unable to find the mentioned confession online.

Did [Ilya Ponomarev](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ilya_Ponomarev) confess or hint he could be behind this?

Even more sources accuse him (Ksenia Sobchak, sources associated with Navalny) of being the culprit but this is outside of the scope of this question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes and no.

Earlier this year, he [took credit](https://x.com/Alkahest_K/status/1718852010945188045?s=20) for arranging protests through the channel.

He again [bragged about](https://x.com/msinformation22/status/1718806782955466790?s=20) operating the channel in August.

Immediately following the anti-Semitic protests, however, he changed his tone and [claimed](https://twitter.com/maximkireev/status/1718714113189085244) he had had no contact with the channel for a year.

It's technically incorrect that he took credit for the anti-Semitic mobbing. However, his involvement is easily inferred from his earlier statements.

Comment: Left out of this answer is whether the channel instigated the mobbing. FWTW, Putin claimed more broadly it was Western intelligence agencies that were behind. https://www.bbc.com/news/world-67267339

Comment: As for one of your Tweet links (1st) claiming "Ukrainian weapons and Western weapons supplied to Ukraine ending up in Hamas"... Hrmm... If the tweed had more than 68 views as it has presently, I'd probably ask a Q based on that here.

Comment: @Fizz I do think the greater context you're asking about is relevant here. I don't have an answer, but those interested in this Q may be interested to explore. https://fediverse.giorgiocomai.eu/notice/AbJU0OydboupRdvq8u

Comment: @Fizz the statement about Ukraine is the author's opinion(basically, since Ponomarev is in Ukraine, he must be coordinating with Ukranian intelligence + HAMAS posted videos with American antitank missiles, they came from Ukraine via the black market. The later is debatable, since those were also supplied to Anti-Assad fighters in Syria, but there have been western reports of weapons being sold from Ukraine, especially in the chaos of the early days, when they were handed out to local militias), but the subtitles are accurate, he does take credit for protests organized on that channel.

Comment: @Fizz the channel 100% instigated the mob, what Putin is claiming is that Western intelligence agencies gave the channel admins their marching orders.